# How to use installed pear file(UIMA RUTA) in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, uima, ruta

Actually i'm trying to integrate UIMA RUTA into maven project using pear file. But I don't know how to proceed after installing the pear file in maven project because of broken links in user guide(https://uima.apache.org/doc-uima-pears.html). Can I know any solution to integrate RUTA into maven? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never did that, but it's on my todo list for a long time. If nobody answers your question, I will when I find the time for PEARs.

Comment: Thanks Peter Kluegl. I believe I will find/get the solution soon.